# clearInterval function not clearing setInterval function

Tags: javascript

I utilized this resource to structure my code: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){ ogpeWrapper() }, 10);

function ogpeWrapper() {
    $("#breadcrumbWrapper, #leftColWrapper, #rightColWrapper").wrapAll('<div id="colWrapperContainer"></div>');
}(jQuery);

function myStopFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById('colWrapperContainer')) {
     clearInterval(intervalID);
     setIntervalID = undefined;
    }    
}
```

My ogpeWrapper function is running, but the clearInterval function is not.

Basically, once $("#breadcrumbWrapper, #leftColWrapper, #rightColWrapper").wrapAll(''); runs, I want the interval to stop running it.

Edit - 12:24pm CST:

This is the base code I utilize to wrap the listed elements -

```
(function($) { 
    $("#breadcrumbAds, #breadcrumbWrapper, #containerTopParsys, #leftColWrapper, #rightColWrapper").wrapAll('<div id="colWrapperContainer"></div>');
})(jQuery);
```

This code works, but it doesn't process the change until after the DOM has completely loaded.  I need the function to work as soon as those elementals are all available.  So I need to use a setInterval to process the function, then clear the interval once the function is processed.

If anyone knows of another way to do this, besides a setIterval, please let me know.

Comment: Where are you calling `myStopFunction()` ?

Comment: sidenote: you pass `jQuery` to `ogpeWrapper` but inside anyway use global alias, because your `ogpeWrapper` definition without params

Comment: I used "function myStopFunction()" based on the http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp link referenced above.  I am completely new to javascript, so I don't know what I am wrong.

Comment: Why are you doing: `function ogpeWrapper(){ //.. }(jQuery);`?  Why do you have the `(jQuery)` there?

Comment: This was my original function: (function($) { $("#breadcrumbWrapper, #leftColWrapper, #rightColWrapper").wrapAll('<div id="colWrapperContainer"></div>');})(jQuery);  and the code above is my attempt to set and stop an interval.  The code in the question is based off of http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a **definite** if else condition within the variable so you know exactly when it will *start* and when it will *stop*. Also, because the minimum millisecond interval timing is **not consistent across browsers**, although you want it to detect really fast, I would recommend a "safer" number and use 100 as the minimum instead. The `.length` method is a handy little way for you to check if an element is on a page; You can use it as a pseudo dynamic true/false conditional.  Lastly, in your `.wrapAll()` tag, I swapped your single and double quotes, as it is best practice to do such.

```
var colWrapper = setInterval(function(){    
    if ($('div#colWrapperContainer').length > 0) {
        var doNothing = "";
        clearInterval(colWrapper);
    } else {
        $("#breadcrumbWrapper, #leftColWrapper, #rightColWrapper").wrapAll("<div id='colWrapperContainer'></div>");
    }
}, 100);
```

Here is a working example for your reference [Wrap Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/44vgne3u/)

**Update:**

Example for putting the script inside the `<body>` tag (**no** window.load/document.ready) so that it runs independently as soon as it is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483000/clearinterval-function-not-clearing-setinterval-function/33483267#33483267
//Auto Wrap Solution
//Alexander Dixon [11-02-2015]
var wrapThese = $("#breadcrumbWrapper, #leftColWrapper, #rightColWrapper");
var colWrapper = setInterval(function () {
    if ($('div#colWrapperContainer').length > 0) {
        var doNothing = "";
        clearInterval(colWrapper);
    } else {
        wrapThese.wrapAll('<div id="colWrapperContainer"></div>').addClass('success');
    }
}, 100);
//]]> 

</script>
```

Comment: This solution does succeed in wrapping the elements, however, it doesn't work until after the page has finished loading.  The reason I needed to use an interval to process this is so that it would load as soon as the elements were detected, rather than after the whole DOM had loaded.

Comment: I've updated my example to include a method that will fire the script immediately. If you want to test, click the "Wrap Example" link, and check "no wrap - in body" in the drop down on the left side.

Comment: If only I was able to do so.  Unfortunately our CMS limits that type of interaction.

Comment: Does your content management system allow for adding references in the header? I would assume so if you are able to reference jQuery.  If that is the case, you should be able to create a JavaScript file with the above code.